# Is it possible and advisable to construct a generator returning unique values from a collection

Tags: python, generator, python-2.7

Currently I'm doing this:

```
# duplicates is a list
uniques = list(set(duplicates))
```

However, uniques is often transitory. Would it be better to construct a generator for uniques? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible benefits from using generators instead of static collections, of which only one (possibly) applies here:

- Memory usage. Does not apply here, because to generate uniques you need O(n) memory this way or the other
- Time - if you expect to consume only part of the generated output, then you can save time by producing it lazily. So if this is your case, then maybe using a generator will save you some processing power. Of course to generate uniques lazily you need to remember the set of values already produced (see above) and filter those out as you go.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need a list, just use `set(duplicates)` instead. That roughly halves your memory use. Sets are iterable.

Alternatively, you can define a generator:

```
def uniques(it):
    seen = set()
    for x in it:
        if x not in seen:
            yield x
            seen.add(x)
```

but my hunch is that this will be a lot slower than just constructing a set in one go. In any case, the memory consumption is about the same.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clearly to me what you're hoping to achieve by using a generator.

One thing is clear: it won't lower memory requirements, since in order to establish whether the current element is unique, the generator would need to know all previously seen unique elements.

Also, the purpose of constructing the list in `list(set(...))` is not entirely clear. Why not just stick with the set that you're already constructing?